# ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build c90ad64e-2c2f-4ad0-a250-160de6f315df status: FAILURE

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, gcloud

I am trying to deploy my Django application to gcloud and I keep getting this error, any ideas what this means?

File upload done.
Updating service [default]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build c90ad64e-2c2f-4ad0-a250-160de6f315df status: FAILURE
Error ID: c84b3231
Error type: UNKNOWN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

never mind, I found out the error was due to a build error, I had an unused pip install in my requirements.txt file. I deleted it and everything is working now.